# R: How to aggregate several data frames into a txt file via for loop?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have several csv files containing date and precipitation info. Here is the sample data:

[three csv files - sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyk5vvt7o7kxydj/csv_files.zip?dl=1)

**Goal:**

I want to read all of them one by one, then:

1- separate the date column into year, month, day.

2- grab the a specific column from each of them.

3- create a data frame for the extracted info from each csv file.

4- Finally, paste all these frames into a txt file.

This is my code to do so:

```
rm(list=ls())

## where is the main folder? 
setwd("C:/Users/Downloadspr_day_ECMWF")  

## reading all csv files:
list_csv_files <- basename(list.files(pattern = ".*_daily_results.*csv", recursive = TRUE))

## a loop here to read all csv files one by one and save their info in one txt file:
result <- list()
counter <- 1

for (i in 1:length(list_csv_files)){ 
  MyData <- read.csv(list_csv_files[[i]], header=TRUE, sep=",")
  head(MyData)

  ## separating year , month , date from the "Date.Precipitation_mm" column inside the csv file:
  date_column <- MyData$Date.Precipitation_mm  
  date_column

  year_date <- format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y")
  month_date <- format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%m")
  day_date <- format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%d")

  ## reading Alberta columns in MyData :
  Alberta_column <- MyData$Alberta
  Alberta_column

  ## creating a data frame to put our data inside it:
  txt_file_data_frame <- data.frame(year_date, month_date, day_date, Alberta_column)

  ## a counter to save all data frames consecutively:
  for (j in 1:length(txt_file_data_frame)) {
    result[[counter]] <- txt_file_data_frame[j]
    counter <- counter + 1
  }

}

## write the txt file:
write.table(txt_file_data_frame, file = "myTXT.txt", row.names = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

But the generated txt file is **ONLY** contained the last csv file info!! Like this:

[image]

**I want to save all data frames in the final txt file.**

Does anybody know the solution to this challenge?

Any help or comment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's a fancy "torn page" view of sample data. While I'm curious to know what you used to make it ... please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. On a related note, when (*not if*) links to data files go stale, the question becomes unreproducible, please just give us sample data (`dput` or `data.frame`).

Comment: I recommend against doing this in a `for` loop and iteratively building a frame: while it works logically, know that R will copy the entire `data.frame` each time you add rows to it, so as you keep adding files it will slow down significantly. It's better to load each file once into a `list` and combine them all at once. For instance, to ask the question in your title, perhaps `alldat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(...), read.csv))`.

Comment: One option would be to move the `write.table` inside the loop and use the option `append=TRUE` and `col.names=F`. This is inefficient if you have a lot of files, writing to disk is time consuming.

Comment: r2evans, thanks for your comment. The reason why I am using pictures and sharing toy codes and sample data is to make things straight forward for those who want to run the code by themselves. By the way, sorry for the incontinence this may cause. As for torn page, I use Snagit to do so. It is free. Just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You writing out `txt_file_data_frame` when you should be writing out `result`.

Without changing your code just replace the second `for` loop, which you don't need at all with:

```
## creating a data frame to put our data inside it:   
txt_file_data_frame <- data.frame(year_date, month_date, day_date, Alberta_column)

result[[i]] <- txt_file_data_frame
} # end of for loop
```

Then to write out your file, bind together your results and write to disk

```
txt_out <- do.call(rbind, result)

## write the txt file:
write.table(txt_out, file = "myTXT.txt", row.names = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

You can also drop `counter` as it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks so much MxblsdI. It works great for me. However, we just need a simple displacement like this: `txt_out <- do.call(rbind, result)`

Comment: oops. Edited to reflect @Canada2015 comment. I always get that function backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tidyverse` package, you don't need the `for` loop. Check if this workaround is what you need. I tried to explain all the steps in the comments.

```r
# install required packages
if (!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse")
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
if (!require("here")) install.packages("here")
#> Loading required package: here
#> here() starts at /tmp/RtmpRFktCG/reprex6c99164b38dd
if (!require("fs")) install.packages("fs")
#> Loading required package: fs

# create a new folder to save the data you shared
dir_create("csv-data")

# get the zip file
csv <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyk5vvt7o7kxydj/csv_files.zip?dl=1"
zip_name <- "csv.zip"
download.file(url = csv, destfile = here("csv-data", zip_name))

# descompress the zip file
unzip(zipfile = here("csv-data", zip_name), exdir = here("csv-data"))

# get data
data <-
  # inform the folder
  here("csv-data") %>%
  # search for csv files
  dir_ls(regexp = "\\.csv") %>% 
  # read and bind the rows
  map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "source") %>% 
  # which files do the lines come from?
  mutate(source = basename(source)) %>% 
  # create date columns based on the previous one
  separate(
    col = Date, 
    into = c("year", "month", "day"), 
    sep = "-"
    ) %>% 
  # select columns 
  select(year, month, day, Alberta)
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   X1 = col_character(),
#>   `Date/Precipitation_mm` = col_date(format = ""),
#>   Alberta = col_double(),
#>   Athabasca = col_double(),
#>   Beaver = col_double(),
#>   Hay_GreatSlave = col_double(),
#>   Milk = col_double(),
#>   NorthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Peace_Slave = col_double(),
#>   SouthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Date = col_date(format = "")
#> )
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   X1 = col_character(),
#>   `Date/Precipitation_mm` = col_date(format = ""),
#>   Alberta = col_double(),
#>   Athabasca = col_double(),
#>   Beaver = col_double(),
#>   Hay_GreatSlave = col_double(),
#>   Milk = col_double(),
#>   NorthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Peace_Slave = col_double(),
#>   SouthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Date = col_date(format = "")
#> )
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   X1 = col_character(),
#>   `Date/Precipitation_mm` = col_date(format = ""),
#>   Alberta = col_double(),
#>   Athabasca = col_double(),
#>   Beaver = col_double(),
#>   Hay_GreatSlave = col_double(),
#>   Milk = col_double(),
#>   NorthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Peace_Slave = col_double(),
#>   SouthSaskatchewan = col_double(),
#>   Date = col_date(format = "")
#> )

# check data
data
#> # A tibble: 1,096 x 4
#>    year  month day      Alberta
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 1950  01    01    0.00131   
#>  2 1950  01    02    0.00170   
#>  3 1950  01    03    0.00142   
#>  4 1950  01    04    0.000156  
#>  5 1950  01    05    0.00105   
#>  6 1950  01    06    0.000792  
#>  7 1950  01    07    0.000622  
#>  8 1950  01    08    0.000267  
#>  9 1950  01    09    0.000339  
#> 10 1950  01    10    0.00000134
#> # … with 1,086 more rows

# save
data %>% 
  write_delim(path = here("csv-data", "myTXT.txt"), delim = "\t")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What a professional method. It works perfectly. However, since the toy code I have shared here is a part of a huge script, I would go with the next answer which made a little change in my toy code. You are a great coder Karlo. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you only write the last iteration of `txt_file_data_frame` (re-assigned in each loop) to file and never use the `results` object. Simply assign to list, outside loop bind all rows, and then write to file. Also `counter` is not needed since you can use the `for` iterator, `i`:

```
## reading all csv files:
list_csv_files <- list.files(pattern = ".*_daily_results.*csv", recursive = TRUE)

## INITIALIZE LIST WITH LENGTH
df_list <- vector(mode=list, length=length(list_csv_files))

for (i in 1:length(list_csv_files)){ 
  MyData <- read.csv(list_csv_files[[i]], header=TRUE, sep=",")
  head(MyData)

  ## separating year , month , date from the "Date.Precipitation_mm" column
  date_column <- MyData$Date.Precipitation_mm  
  date_column

  ## creating a data frame to put our data inside it:
  txt_file_data_frame <- data.frame(
                year_date = format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y"),
                month_date = format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y"),
                day_date = format(as.Date(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%d"),
                Alberta_column = MyData$Alberta
  )

  ## a counter to save all data frames consecutively:      
  df_list[[i]] <- txt_file_data_frame      
}

# BIND ALL DFs TO ONE    
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

## write the txt file:
write.table(final_df, file = "myTXT.txt", row.names = FALSE, 
            dec = ".", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are awesome. I wish I could write the high level codes like you. As I described above, I accepted the second answer. However, your method work great.